# Does Android Fresco Library for android API work in DP or PX?

Tags: android, fresco

This may seem a simple question, but I am not able to find the answer anywhere.

When dealing the APIs of Facebook's Fresco, are the variables related to sizing defined in PX or DP?

Regards,

Comment: which one? [ResizeOptions](http://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/common/ResizeOptions.html)?

Comment: yes exactly, i mean this one.

Comment: have you read **Class Overview**?

Comment: must have skipped this. thank you for your time anyway :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pskink pointed, the values turned out to be in PX.
Below the reference URL: http://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/common/ResizeOptions.html